# Make some transformation to a column and then set it as index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let say I have below `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [3,4,5,6]})
dat['A1'] = dat['A'].astype(str) + '_Something'
dat.set_index('A1')
```

While this alright, I want to achieve below things

1. Instead of having this line `dat['A1'] = dat['A'].astype(str) + '_Something'`, can I transform the column `A` on the fly and directly pass that transformed values to `dat.set_index`? My transformation function is rather little complex, so I am looking for some general approach
2. After setting index, can I remove `A1` which is now sitting as like the header of index

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `np.array` to [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). So, just chain [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) after the transformation, and make sure that you set the `inplace` parameter to `True` inside `set_index`.

```
dat.set_index(
    (dat['A'].astype(str) + '_Something') # transformation
    .to_numpy(), 
    inplace=True)

print(dat)

             A  B
1_Something  1  3
2_Something  2  4
3_Something  3  5
4_Something  4  6
```

So, generalized with a function applied, that would be something like:

```
def f(x):
    y = f'{x}_Something'
    return y
    
dat.set_index(dat['A'].apply(f).to_numpy(), inplace=True)
```